# Dynamics CRM - Text inside customer field on case entity won't update

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a problem with getting the text inside the customerid field on the case-form to update

[image]

As you can see on the picture above, I've created a contact named "Test Contact" and an account named "Test Account".

I have a workflow running in the background with the condition: if a contact is in the customer-field AND the contact belongs to an account, then update the record with moving the customer (which is a contact) to the contact field, and then get the company in the customer field.

The problem is (as shown in the picture) that the customer field don't show the right text. Because customer details is updated with "Test Account" which is the company that "Test Contact" belongs to. Also, if I click on the "test contact" I also get in the "Test Account" form. So all the references is okey, but the text is wrong.

I've tried different ways to solve this problem, but as for now, I'm a bit short on what to do next.

The workflow
[image]

Update record
[image]

Comment: If you refresh the form, does everything display correctly?

Comment: @Polshgiant No, it stays like this until I manually remove the text from the field.

Comment: Can you show us your workflow logic and the update record form (in the workflow where you define which value will go in which field)

Comment: @YacineZine I've updated the first post with images of the workflow and the update record

Comment: Can you try to split the workflow into 2 seperate workflows. 1 workflow will set the Contact lookup. The second workflow will trigger on update of the contact field set the Company of the contact in the Customer field.

Comment: @YacineZine I've tried that as well, but still gets the same error. I've also tried to create a child workflow that is triggered when the first one is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with an wait condition that timedout until the contact field had data, and then got the company of the contact. 
It takes a few seconds extra, but at least it solved the label error

Comment: Are you using turboforms? Because it can be related to that.I've seen many cases where a timeout was helpful when doing similar operations on turboforms.